# Vertically center text. Display Table. Div height not increasing

Tags: html, css

Actually, I am practicing on centering a text vertically in a div. Have read many instructions online. But liked the one in which I can display a container div as table and then the child div inside it (in this case .middle) to be displayed as table-cell. It works. But the only problem is that whenever I try to set the .container div height to 100%, the div squeezes to wrap itself to the text line. However, when I define the height of the .container div explicitly, then I am able to get the desired width with the text perfectly centered.

Can anyone explain why is that? Please refer to the image screenshots to understand this better.

[image: Screenshot with .container height:200px]
[image: Screenshot with .container height:100%]

```css
 html,
 body {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   left: 0px;
   top: 0px;
   margin-top: 0px;
   margin-right: 0px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   margin-left: 0px;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 153, 1);
 }
 .container {
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
 .middle {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
 }
 .inner {
   display: table;
   margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="middle">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In order to work with `%` as the value for the height you need to set the values of the parent elements too. In this case if you want full height of the window `html and body` tags must be `100%` too; or the parent of the container must have a fixed height.

Comment: edited your post and turned your code into a snippet .. and i do not understand your question, it works as expected

Answer (score 1):

The parent container should also have its height explicitly stated in order to be able to use `percentage` on the child. Otherwise it doesn't know what the `100%` value refers to, unless you give `position: absolute;` and you set a different container (with a height) to `position: relative;`

Comment: Ok, i understand now. In this case the height of body needs to be defined in pixels. but what if i don't want to explicitly define height in pixels ? (For the purpose that if i plan to add a continuous text flowing vertically to 2-3 pages) I want the child and parent div to expand horizontally. And also keeping the center text feature!

Comment: It doesn't have to be stated in `pixels`. You can use `%` or `vh \ vw`. In you case you could try using `min-height`.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to paste the body portion in the css code above. lease see the code now, the height of the body is defined as 100%

Comment: @serious_coder you need the value for the `html` tag too

Comment: don't know how to post a fiddle. would appreciate someone's help. but have updated the above code with html set to height 100%

Comment: Follow the link in my previous comment and you'll easily figure it out. Then you just have to post a link.